# How do I delete a Rollup custom objects

Tags: roll-up-summary, rolluphelper

I would like to know how to delete a Rollup custom field from Salesforce. These fields use the Rollup helper installed package.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the application and then delete the Rollup Custom field, later re install the application.

Comment: If you just delete the Jobs that you have created for Rollup Helper (without having to fulling uninstall the app), you should then be able to delete the fields with no issue.